# Can't type closing angle bracket in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, kali-linux, input

After searching the web for two hours, fooling with keyboard settings and restarting my computer I have not been able to find a solution. I noticed the problem while trying to program in `nano` when I tried to `include` a header file. When I try to type the closing angle bracket a black square with beveled edges and a white circle crossed through shows up and doesn't type the key. I have used `showkey` to make sure it was capturing my keyboard input and it is.

```
keycode  42 press
keycode  52 press
keycode  52 release
keycode  42 release
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Screen capture of [black square](https://postimg.org/image/dhy7fxd81/).

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the symbol please?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The black square that appears or the symbol I'm trying to type?

Comment: The latter. I think most people know what an angle bracket is. Its one of > right? as opposed to a square bracket ] or a brace/curly bracket }.

Comment: Yes this > and I provided a screenshot of the black square that appears upon trying to type >. (Copied and pasted >)

Comment: It might be worth checking your keyboard layout settings.

Comment: @GregHNZ I have, however I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Is that Gnome?  Seems like you might have a global shortcut that is mapped to > and whatever it is calling is not working.  That is in Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts I think.

Comment: @Paul YESSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!! You're a genius! Apparently, unbeknownst to me, it was mapped to "Go to the next track". I can't thank you enough!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you might have a global shortcut that is mapped to > and whatever it is calling is not working.

That is in Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts in Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
*set keyboard language to yours *
sudo apt-get install console-common
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data

now try left alt  and = and / keys.